# Protecting red brick patio from green moss

Tags: waterproofing, brick, patio, moss

My other half has just finished laying a brick patio.  We're looking for some way to reduce or minimise the growth of green moss which makes these bricks really slippery, more-so in winter with increased shade and decreased daylight.

I have a half-tin of brick sealant left over from when these bricks were a wall (pre-quake, 7 years ago)

- Name "Cemix Penetrating clear masonry sealer solvent based"
- Description "low-viscosity silane-siloxane treatment which penetrates into the surface to produce a hydrophobic lining to the pores and capillaries"

Can I use this stinky solvent on our brick patio, or will it make the surface slipperier in the damp?

[image]

Slightly related to [How do I remove moss from an outdoor brick walkway?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3465/how-do-i-remove-moss-from-an-outdoor-brick-walkway) but this is fresh and clean and we want to keep it that way as long as possible.

Comment: I've done a test by painting a spare brick, and the water does not soak in.  So that suggests moss will have a harder time getting established.  Also that winter water will sit on top and freeze leading to ice.  And that we're not dipping the bricks in, so the other five sides will still be vulnerable to water soaking in.